# Facebook OmniAuth Api with Rails - User Friends List

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I am using Omniauth gem ,I want to access user's friends list how I can do that.

Also while accessing some of user's attributes like headline ,industry gettting errors - Tried accessing non-existing fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
profile = @graph.get_object("me")
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

Comment: Tried this but getting this in friends    --- 
        internal: [] 
       ivars:
            :@paging: 
            :@raw_response:
           data: []
          :@api: !ruby/object:Koala::Facebook::API
           access_token: 'access token XXXXX'
           app_secret:

Comment: may be version issue try friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends", api_version: 'v2.0')